# Non editable field permission setting

Tags: community, custom-object, custom-field, salesforce-id, fields

How to set this type of field(e.g. Account number) permission where permissions(Visible and Read-Only) are non-editable(greyed out) using any profile?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Few Mandatory fields which define the very existence of object cannot have read only access,
like the Name field which forms the index for that record.

You can find other ways to make them read only

Write a validation rules avoid edition of the field if you need to prevent user from changing once user enters value.

One good example on how to make use of custom setting and write validation rule is below

http://www.verticalcoder.com/2012/07/26/custom-settings/

You can combine multiple fields and write validations as well in single rule

```
 AND(
OR(
  ISCHANGED( Name),
  ISCHANGED( StageName),
  ISCHANGED( CloseDate),
  ISCHANGED( Amount )),
 NOT(IsNew()),
 $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator")
```